# Any limit to number of properties on a .NET Class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Received a spec to add over 800 properties to an object. Is their any 'limits' to the number of Properties an object can have in C# (or .NET)?

Is their any performance impacts to be concerned with in regards to objects of this class with this many properties?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure there is some limit. But I assume it's much higher than 1000.

Comment: I would love to know what your architect did before he became an architect. Maybe a musician playing 200 instruments at the same time and did it perfectly?

Comment: How do you name these? Please dont say `Property001` -> `Property800`

Comment: Can you explain what kind of data this class should hold, and why somebody thought that having this many properties is a good idea?

Comment: @leppie - Don't be ridiculous. Surely `Property000` to `Property799` would be better style.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK: What are the odds the spec writer would even know that? :)

Comment: Sounds like whoever wrote the spec doesn't know about basic data structures like arrays :/.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The metadata can have up to 24-bit references/definitions per assembly. Being a property, you need 2 methods per property. Hence the limit will be 23-bit, or `1 << 23 - 1` for the entire assembly.

**Update:**

If they are only read-only properties, the limit would be `1 << 24 - 1`.

**Answer to second question:**

No, there will be no performance overhead. Simple properties are likely to be inlined by the JIT.

**Some thoughts:**

You will never reach the above limit. Imagine having 16 million properties. That will require 16 million strings stored for the names too. Say the average name is 8 chars, then you are looking at a string table size of ~256MB (property name + method name), and then you havent even started coding yet. Just a thought.

Comment: Doesn't the property itself need a metadata slot too? Which would result in something like 2^24/3

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Different tables :)

Comment: Nice to see an answer which is based in actually knowing the answer, rather than vague "I don't think there is a limit, but that is sure bad design" ones. +1

Comment: @Jodrell: Me? About 25wpm. After almost a decade of coding, I still cant touch type :(

Comment: So, assuming 8 hour days and no slacking and that you use the prop snippet so only have to type about 4 words per property... 2796 working days to get there.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the accepted answer is correct. We have just hit a problem with our assembly that adding any new property does build the code, but trying to load the assembly with reflection results in **File is corrupt. HRESULT 0x8013110E**

Removing any property after that allows to load the assembly with reflection again.

I obtained the metadata stats with ildasm:

```
C:\temp> ildasm.exe xyz.dll /stats /out=c:\temp\1.txt
C:\temp> cat C:\temp\1.txt | sls '\bFieldDef\b'

//   FieldDef      - 65534 (655340 bytes) 181 constant
```

Looks like a pretty clear 16 bits limit on FieldDef.